# Is "Let A be any set", A universal or existential quantifier?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This is a very basic question but I can't find anything related on the internet.

I know that Universal quantifiers are "For all x" while existential quantifiers are "For some"

However, the statement for "Let A be any set" is confusing but from what I understand. It's a universal quantifier. However, if someone can clarify then Thank you!

Comment: *for any* and *for all* have similar meanings here

Comment: (+1) This issue is particularly vexatious when authors use "for any" in the hypothesis of an if-then statement, e.g., "If condition $P(A)$ holds for any set $A$, then ...." Here as well, the meaning is "... _for every_ set $A$...." The take-away point is _don't write like that_. :)

Answer (score 1):

If $P(A)$ is some property of a set $A$, one may write something like
$$\forall A: P(A).$$
Proofs of such statements then often go as follows: You pick some arbitrary set $A$ (and write "Let $A$ be any set"), and prove that $P(A)$ holds. This allows the proof to be more readable. Otherwise, you'd need to carry the quantifier through the whole proof, making it hard to follow.

Answer (score 0):

I shall explain this with an example. Consider the statement $S:= $ "the empty set is contained inside every set".

$S$ may be rephrased as:

1. For every set $A$, $\varnothing \subset A$.
2. For all sets $A$, $\varnothing \subset A$.
3. Let $A$ be any set. Then, $\varnothing \subset A$.
4. Choose an arbitrary set $A$. Then, $\varnothing \subset A$.

There is hardly any math here, it is essentially just mathematical jargon. Yes, all these statements involve the universal quantifier $\forall$. They are just phrased differently in language, but all of them have the same meaning.